# Reference for Mori program

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Are there some introductory and self-contained books or lecture notes for Mori-program?  It would be much better to have enough examples.

Comment: Kollar has a very usable introduction. http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1987-17-02/S0273-0979-1987-15548-0/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two good introductions to the Mori program and the geometry of higher dimensional varieties are

*Kenji Matsuki*, Introduction to the Mori program, Universitext. New York, NY: Springer (ISBN 0-387-98465-8/hbk). xxiii, 478 p. (2002). [ZBL0988.14007](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0988.14007).

*Olivier Debarre*, Higher-dimensional algebraic geometry, Universitext. New York, NY: Springer. xiii, 233 p. (2001). [ZBL0978.14001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0978.14001).